# Insert a document in an elasticsearch index and have it analysed by the analyser

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, tokenize

I have defined an analyser like:

```
PUT /train-music
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "music_analyser": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "snowball"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the mapping of my train-music index is like:

```
PUT /train-music/_mapping/music
{
  "properties": {
    "instruments": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "music_analyser"
    }
  }
}
```

Then i'm inserting a document:

```
POST /train-music/music/1
{
 "id": 1452,
 "style": "rock",
 "instruments":"battery, electric guitar, guitar, piano"
 }
```

I was expecting something like (I fake the stemmisation):

{
    "id": 1452,
    "style": "rock",
    "instruments":"batter, electr, guit, guit, pian"
 }

But when i execute this: `GET /train-music/music/1` instead of having my instrument field well tokenise and stemmed I got the same thing as my input. What should I do to make my analyser work on the document I want to index, should I add something when I want to index my document?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do anything, this is done behind the scene by Elasticsearch. If you want to see what terms have actually been indexed, you can use

```
GET /train-music/music/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": ["instruments"]
}
```

Even before indexing, you can check to see if the analyzer works by using the [`_analyze` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html):

```
GET /train-music/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "music_analyser",
  "text" : "battery, electric guitar, guitar, piano"
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)